# Carrossel Bootstrap não funciona quando adiciono links

Tags: html, carousel, boot

Quando adiciono a tag a no meu html o carrossel Bootstrap para de funcionar.
Obs: já tentei tirar o código em php e deixar ele puro, e mesmo assim ele para de funcionar quando eu acrescento a tag de link.

```html
        <!-- Carrossel -->
        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide banner" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner banner-max">
                <!-- Loop de fotos para o carrossel -->
                <?php
                $links = array(
                    "https://cataguases.mg.gov.br/",
                    "https://cataguases.cdls.org.br/",
                    "https://www.facebook.com/ACIC-Associa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-Comercial-e-Industrial-de-Cataguases-422881014559226/",
                    "https://sebraemg.com.br/salamineiradoempreendedor/",
                    "https://contrata.mg.gov.br/"
                );
                for ($k = 1; $k < 8; $k++)
                { ?>
                    <a href="<?= $links[$k - 1] ?>" target="_BLANK">
                        <div class="carousel-item <?php if ($k == 1) echo 'active' ?>">
                            <img src="../../../public/img/carrossel0<?= $k; ?>.png" class="d-block w-100 image-carousel" alt="...">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" style="z-index:20" data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon span-carousel" style="z-index:20" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden" style="z-index:20">Previous</span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next" style="z-index:20" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon span-carousel" style="z-index:20" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden" style="z-index:20">Next</span>
            </button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score -3):

tem alguns erros aí, primeiro é bom pegar a documentação oficial [aqui](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/),

Os outros erros são: tirar o link de fora da div e jogar para dentro

colocar o `href="#carouselExampleControls"` nos seus buttons e

trocar o `data-bs-slide="next"` por `data-slide="prev"`

segue um código de exemplo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Carrossel -->
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide banner" data-bs-ride="carousel">
   <div class="carousel-inner banner-max">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
         <a href="<?= $links[$k - 1] ?>" target="_BLANK">
         <img src="https://i0.wp.com/saberanimal.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/mae-e-filho-pangolins-foto-de-Elyane-And-Cedric-Jacquet.jpg?fit=1190%2C793&ssl=1" class="d-block w-100 image-carousel" alt="...">
         </a>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
         <a href="<?= $links[$k - 1] ?>" target="_BLANK">
         <img src="https://exame.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/GettyImages-1198472987-e1591879251748-1.jpg" class="d-block w-100 image-carousel" alt="...">
         </a>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
         <a href="<?= $links[$k - 1] ?>" target="_BLANK">
         <img src="https://i0.wp.com/saberanimal.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/pangolim_carne-scaled.jpg?resize=2048%2C1400&ssl=1" class="d-block w-100 image-carousel" alt="...">
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <button href="#carouselExampleControls" class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" style="z-index:20" data-slide="prev">
   <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon span-carousel" style="z-index:20" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="visually-hidden" style="z-index:20">Previous</span>
   </a>
   <!--            <button class="carousel-control-next" style="z-index:20" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon span-carousel" style="z-index:20" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden" style="z-index:20">Next</span>
      </button>-->
   <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
   <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```